# Make ImageView display black portions of image as different color

Tags: android, colors, imageview, picasso

How can I replace the black color with transparent color (or some other color) in an ImageView?

I load image from web using Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load("www.abc.com/a.png").into(myImageView);
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

The image itself contains the black background, which I want to remove. I tried using `myImageView.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Primož 'c0dehunter' Kralj see my answer hope this will help you out.

Comment: @akhilesh0707 https://freesound.org/data/displays/186/186942_2594536_wave_M.png

Comment: Correct; I want to replace the black part of it with some different color or make it transparent in those areas.

Comment: @Primož'c0dehunter'Kralj try my answer attached image

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Andy Developer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44968385/1181261) helped, but I had to manually convert black pixels to pixels of my liking. It is working, although I am not sure if this is the best way.

[image]

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(IMAGE_URL).into(new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
    {
        Bitmap copy = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(),true);

        int [] allpixels = new int [copy.getHeight()*copy.getWidth()];
        copy.getPixels(allpixels, 0, copy.getWidth(), 0, 0, copy.getWidth(), copy.getHeight());

        int replacementColor = Color.parseColor("#34495E");
        for(int i = 0; i < allpixels.length; i++) {
            if(allpixels[i] == Color.BLACK)
                allpixels[i] = replacementColor;
        }

        copy.setPixels(allpixels, 0, copy.getWidth(), 0, 0, copy.getWidth(), copy.getHeight());

        myImageView.setImageBitmap(copy);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) { }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) { }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
Picasso.with(this).load("Your URL").into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
        {
           bitmap.eraseColor(Color.argb(AAA,RRR,GGG,BBB));
           OR
           bitmap.eraseColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor));
           imageView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't replace the black color in the PNG that I load into imageview.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't do anything. The PNG that I load already has black background (which I want to remove).

Comment: If it is not working you can use Canvas to change the bitmap color.

Comment: remember to hold a reference to the Target. Picasso only holds weak references to Targets, and they will be gc'd.